# Getting { "user": [ "This field is required."] } on Postman everttime I try to post

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a sign up api using createAPIView on Django rest Framework. Everytime I post data on Postman it returns the above error although it gets response when I run it in browser. Also the image field is causing problem in raw data on postman. I have tried a lot of things but nothng has seemed to work. What am I supposed to do?

serializers

```
 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
        )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8)

     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'username','password')
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}



class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    code = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    avatar = serializers.FileField(use_url=False)


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user',None)
        image = validated_data.pop('avatar')
        upr=UserProfile.objects.create(user=user_data, image=image**validated_data)
        return upr
```

views

```
  class UserCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    user_serializer = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser,FileUploadParser)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,     status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong here, but in terms of your image issues: I think it has to do with using a wrong encoding type in Postman. When uploading data through a form, you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Django admin forms handles this for you. (Best Google this for better information).

Next time, please don't put two different questions in a single issue if you can avoid it. Also be more clear than "it doesn't work" or "it's funky".

Comment: I am not using html form. I am a complete newbie on REST.Can you please tell me where I have to mention this ?

Comment: In terms of your real question: Postman and your browser will use different user sessions. Do you have a logged in user in both applications? Also, are you not accidentally putting GET params in body, or POST params in GET param area? (They're two different things in Postman).

Comment: I dont think user is logged in anywhere and I am using Post on Postman.

Comment: In Postman there is a "headers" section in each request tab, where you can add custom encoding. There happens to be an example here under "Syntax": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Furthermore, I'm not experienced or well informed enough to know what you need or are doing. I hope I've given you some handles to help you further your search.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send profile data without creating a user first. And a profile object must be applied to an already existing user.